# What's the fastest way to remove duplicates from an array in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, nsmutablearray, memset, array-algorithms

Prepping for an interview.  I am trying to practice by solving the following problem:  Given an input array of NSNumbers where some of the numbers are duplicated, how can you create another array that only has the unique values in the original array.

I see 2 approaches:

1. Brute-force:  Loop through each element in the array, while at a element compare it against the set of numbers in the unique list, if there is a match, don't store it, else add it to the unique list.  O(n^2) worst case time?
2. Hash-table based approach:  Have a hash-table of length N.   Each element of the has-table is NSSet. Every number is mapped to 0,...N-1 using a hashing function.  If it is exists in the NSSet corresponding to the "mapped-index",  it is not added to "unique array".  if not, it is added to set and unique array.

Is this O(N) complexity?

- I looked two ways to implement approach 2 
  A. NSMutableArray with size of N all initialized to [NSNull null] objects at start.
  B. NSMutableDictionary where key = hashed mapping integer

Code for each approach is below.

I am noticing that 
i. Running time of 2A (array approach) is half of that of 2B (Mutabledictionary approach) for the input array of length 403 shown below(0.055ms vs .12ms).
ii. Running time of 1 is ~ 5 times worse 0.25ms.  If there are not any duplicates,  this discrepancy is even worse.

My Qs are:

1. Is there a better algorithm than 2?
2. Is there a better implementation of algorithm 2?
3. Why is dictionary approach slower?  How can I answer this for myself using Instruments profiling.  I.e how can I know exact time taken by each step using Instruments?

***Code***

***Hashcode function***

```
#define NUM_BUCKETS 127
#define RANDOMIZER 11
#define NUM_ITER 40000

int hashcode(int value)
{
    int retVal = (value*RANDOMIZER)%NUM_BUCKETS ;
    if(retVal<0)
    {
        retVal+=NUM_BUCKETS ;
    }
    return retVal ;
}
```

***1. Brute-Force Approach***

```
    NSMutableArray *smooshedArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] ;
    double startTime ;

    startTime=CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() ;
    for(int iter=0;iter<=NUM_ITER;iter++)
    {
        [smooshedArr removeAllObjects] ;
        [smooshedArr addObject:ints[0]] ;

        int i,j ;
        for(i=1;i<[ints count];i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<[smooshedArr count];j++)
            {
                if([ints[i] intValue] == [smooshedArr[j] intValue])
                {
                    break ;
                }
            }
            if(j==[smooshedArr count])
            {
                [smooshedArr addObject:ints[i]] ;
            }
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"Bruteforce took %.3fms to remove duplicates from array of length %lu",(CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()-startTime)*1000/NUM_ITER,(unsigned long)[ints count]) ;
    NSLog(@"Smooshed arary is %@",smooshedArr) ;
```

***2A. Array based hash table***

```
    NSMutableArray *hashTable = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init] ;

    startTime=CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() ;
    for(int iter=0;iter<=NUM_ITER;iter++)
    {
        [smooshedArr removeAllObjects];
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < NUM_BUCKETS; ++i)
        {
            [hashTable addObject:[NSNull null]];
        }

        [smooshedArr addObject:ints[0]] ;

        int indexToInsert = hashcode([ints[0] intValue]) ;
        hashTable[indexToInsert]=[[NSMutableSet alloc] init] ;
        [hashTable[indexToInsert] addObject:ints[0]] ;

        int i ;
        for(i=1;i<[ints count];i++)
        {
            //Find hascode of element i
            //If the list at index = hashcode in hashCodeArary is empty, then create a NSMutableSet, set toInsert = True
            //If not empty, check if the element exists in the set. If yes, setToInsert=False. If no, setToInsert=True
            int indexToInsert = hashcode([ints[i] intValue]) ;
            BOOL toInsert=false ;

            if(hashTable[indexToInsert] == [NSNull null])
            {
                hashTable[indexToInsert]=[[NSMutableSet alloc] init] ;
                toInsert=true ;
            }
            else
            {
                if(![hashTable[indexToInsert] containsObject:ints[i]])
                    toInsert=true ;
            }
            if(toInsert)
            {
                [hashTable[indexToInsert] addObject:ints[i]] ;
                [smooshedArr addObject:ints[i]] ;
            }
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"MutableArray (no cheat) took %.3fms to remove duplicates from array of length %lu",(CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()-startTime)*1000/NUM_ITER,(unsigned long)[ints count]) ;
```

***2B. Dictionary based hash table***

```
    NSMutableDictionary *hashDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] ;
    //NSLog(@"Start of hashcode approach %.6f", CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()) ;
    startTime=CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() ;
    for(int iter=0;iter<=NUM_ITER;iter++)
    {
        //if(iter <4) NSLog(@"iter start: %.6f", CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()) ;

        //if(iter <4) NSLog(@"init start: %.6f", CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()) ;
          [smooshedArr removeAllObjects];
          [hashDict removeAllObjects] ;
        //if (iter<4) NSLog(@"init end: %.6f", CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()) ;


        [smooshedArr addObject:ints[0]] ;

        int indexToInsert = hashcode([ints[0] intValue]) ;
        hashDict[@(indexToInsert)]=[[NSMutableSet alloc] init] ;
        [hashDict[@(indexToInsert)] addObject:ints[0]] ;

        int i ;
        for(i=1;i<[ints count];i++)
        {
            //Find hascode of element i
            //If the list at index = hashcode in hashCodeArary is empty, then create a NSMutableSet, set toInsert = True
            //If not empty, check if the element exists in the set. If yes, setToInsert=False. If no, setToInsert=True
            int indexToInsert = hashcode([ints[i] intValue]) ;
            BOOL toInsert=false ;

            if(hashDict[@(indexToInsert)] == nil)
            {
                hashDict[@(indexToInsert)]=[[NSMutableSet alloc] init] ;
                toInsert=true ;
            }
            else
            {
                if(![hashDict[@(indexToInsert)] containsObject:ints[i]])
                    toInsert=true ;
            }
            if(toInsert)
            {
                [hashDict[@(indexToInsert)] addObject:ints[i]] ;
                [smooshedArr addObject:ints[i]] ;
            }
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"Dictionary approach: %.3fms to remove duplicates from array of length %lu",(CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()-startTime)*1000/NUM_ITER,(unsigned long)[ints count]) ;
```

***Input tested ON, 430 elements with some dups and averaged over 40000 iterations***

```
   NSArray *ints = @[@(2),@(3),@(4),@(1),@(6),@(9),@(2),@(2),@(3),@(21),@(22),@(45454),@(464642),@(65),@(45454),@(1234),@(3421),@(123),@(1234),@(11111),@(2727272),@(112),@(3),@(4),@(1),@(612211),@(9),@(2),@(2),@(3),@(21),@(22),@(45454),@(464642),@(65),@(45454),@(1234),@(3421),@(123),@(1234),@(11111),@(7272),@(1232),@(3),@(4),@(1),@(60),@(9),@(2),@(2),@(3),@(21),@(22),@(45454),@(464642),@(65),@(45454),@(1234),@(3421),@(123),@(1234),@(11111),@(2727272),@(2),@(3),@(4),@(1),@(6),@(9),@(2),@(2),@(3),@(21),@(22),@(45454),@(464642),@(65),@(45454),@(1234),@(3421),@(123),@(1234),@(11111),@(2727272),@(2),@(3),@(4),@(1),@(6),@(9),@(2),@(2),@(3),@(21),@(22),@(45454),@(464642),@(65),@(45454),@(1234),@(3421),@(123),@(1234),@(11111),@(72),@(2),@(3),@(4),@(1),@(6),@(9),@(2),@(2),@(3),@(21),@(22),@(45454),@(464642),@(65),@(45454),@(1234),@(3421),@(123),@(1234),@(11111),@(13272),@(2),@(3),@(4),@(18),@(6),@(9),@(2),@(2),@(3),@(21),@(22),@(45454),@(464642),@(65),@(45454),@(1234),@(3421),@(123),@(1234),@(11111),@(972),@(2),@(3),@(4),@(1),@(6),@(9),@(2),@(2),@(3),@(21),@(22),@(45454),@(464642),@(65),@(45454),@(1234),@(3421),@(123),@(1234),@(11111),@(3272),@(2),@(3),@(4),@(1),@(69),@(9),@(2),@(2),@(3),@(21),@(22),@(45454),@(464642),@(65),@(45454),@(1234),@(3421),@(123),@(1234),@(11111),@(1272),@(2),@(3),@(4),@(1),@(6),@(9),@(2),@(2),@(3),@(21),@(22),@(45454),@(464642),@(65),@(45454),@(1234),@(3421),@(123),@(1234),@(11111),@(2272),@(2),@(3),@(4),@(1),@(6),@(91),@(2),@(2),@(3),@(21),@(22),@(45454),@(464642),@(65),@(45454),@(1234),@(3421),@(123),@(1234),@(11111),@(7272),@(2),@(3),@(4),@(12),@(6),@(9),@(2),@(2),@(3),@(21),@(22),@(45454),@(464642),@(65),@(45454),@(1234),@(3421),@(123),@(1234),@(111),@(27272),@(2),@(321),@(4),@(1),@(6),@(9),@(2),@(2),@(3),@(21),@(22),@(45454),@(464642),@(65),@(4545411),@(12341),@(34210),@(123),@(1234),@(1111),@(727272),@(11187),@(9086),@(876543),@(74532),@(464642),@(65),@(45454),@(1234),@(3421),@(123),@(1234),@(11111),@(13272),@(2),@(3),@(4),@(18),@(6),@(9),@(2),@(2),@(3),@(21),@(22),@(45454),@(464642),@(658),@(45454),@(12934),@(38421),@(1243),@(12345),@(1112),@(72),@(52),@(3),@(498),@(1),@(6),@(9),@(2),@(2),@(3),@(21),@(22),@(45454),@(464642),@(65),@(45454),@(1234),@(650),@(45454),@(1234),@(3421),@(123),@(1234),@(111),@(27272),@(2),@(321),@(4),@(1),@(6),@(9),@(2),@(2),@(3),@(21),@(22),@(45454),@(464642),@(65),@(4545411),@(12341),@(34210),@(123),@(1234),@(1111),@(727272),@(11187),@(9086),@(876543),@(74532),@(464642),@(65),@(45454),@(1234),@(3421),@(123),@(1234),@(11111),@(13272),@(2),@(3),@(4),@(18),@(6),@(9),@(2),@(2),@(3),@(21),@(22),@(45454),@(464642),@(658),@(45454),@(12934),@(38421),@(1243),@(19992345),@(119875412),@(72),@(52),@(3),@(498),@(1),@(6),@(9),@(2),@(2),@(3),@(21),@(22),@(450454),@(46908764642),@(6753435),@(45498754),@(100234),@(65)] ;
```

Comment: Why use an array? A dictionary would be much better suited for a hash table.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy.  I am finding dictionary approach slower than Array approach even with the "NSNull null" loop.  I have edited my Q to put the full question and code above.  Can you pls take a look?

Comment: If you don't need to keep the order of items, just create a `NSSet` of the array. Problem solved. If you want to keep the order, create a `NSMutableSet` and a `NSMutableArray` to store the result. Iterate over the original array, check if item is in set, if not then add it to set and to output array. 5 lines of code and you can't get better performance.

Comment: Nice solution.  Cut it down by nearly half..Can you make out an answer so I can accept?  Is NSSet using a Hashtable underneath?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are preparing for an interview, I would advise you to use the framework classes that are already implemented. Don't reimplement the wheel. Try to solve the problem from top to bottom. Don't think about details (hash functions), think about the algorithm structure:

In pseudocode:

```
for number in input {
   if number appears for the first time {
      add number to output
   }
}
```

The only problem we have is how to implement the `number appears for the first time`. That's the only point that has some performance implications here.

In Objective-C we can use `NSSet` which is a class created exactly for this problem.

```
NSArray *input = @[... array of numbers];

NSMutableSet *foundNumbers = [NSMutableSet set];
NSMutableArray *output = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSNumber *number in input) {
    if (![foundNumbers containsObject:number])) {
       [foundNumbers addObject:number];
       [output addObject:number];
    }
}

NSLog(@"Output: %@", output);
```

You need only one pass of the input array. The only way you could improve performance is using a different structure than `NSSet`, however `NSSet` is already highly optimized and it's unlikely you will find a better option.

If you want to think out of the box and the numbers in your input are limited to a small enough range (e.g. 0...65000), you can create a `BOOL` array with 65000 items, all initialized to `NO` and use that as a fast set implementation.
However, that will take a lot of memory and it won't pay off unless the `input` array is very long.

Definitely don't implement your own hash tables, `NSDictionary` is already a hash table. What you are doing in your second implementation is just a very obfuscated reimplementation of `NSDictionary`. Buckets work only when you can keep them as a simple array. Once you add hash function to it, you are losing the performance gain.

Also note that the overall quality of code is very important for interviews. Don't use `#define` to declare a constant. Keep a good coding style (I would strongly advice to use spaces around operators). Use iterators instead of `for(;;)` Try to name your variables better than `hashDict` (name your variables for the data they contain).

Now a little secret, there is also a class `NSOrderedSet` which combines `NSArray` and `NSSet` into one object and can solve your problem even easier:

```
NSOrderedSet *orderedSet = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:ints];
NSLog(@"Output: %@", orderedSet);
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Sulthan,  appreciated.  Could you elaborate on "(I would strongly advice to use spaces around operators)"?  Are you referring to adding space after for, if etc?

Comment: @Sultan, can you also tell me if I there is any way to use Instruments to know how long each step of the also takes in the more complicated way I wrote it?

Comment: @SmartHome Operators are `=`, `+`,  `<=`, `==` etc.. This is not an error but it's generally advised to put spaces around binary operators (`1+2` becomes `1 + 2` etc) because it greatly increases readability. You are actually using that in some places (e.g. with `=`, `==`). Using spaces is not required but you should really be consistent and put them either everywhere or nowhere. Most coding standards are also putting spaces after a keyword (`if`, `for`) and I am doing that too but that's not so important as spaces around operators.

Answer (score 0):

Actually using NSOrderedSet is not even necessary – one can get away with just NSSet:

```
NSSet *set = [NSSet setWithArray:ints];
```

If you need an array as output, Key-Value Coding is here to help:

```
NSArray *array =  [ints valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.self"];
```

Comment: `NSSet` won't keep the order of the items.

Comment: @Sulthan, true, but I didn't see such a requirement in OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use extra space(hash), if sequence of numbers in array does not matter but still you don't want to be as slow as brute force then you can sort the array and after that remove duplicates in one pass. Time complexity nlog(n) + n